# Save dropbox user authentication token for future sessions

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to use dropbox's Python SDK to authenticate app users with OAuth2.

I would like to store each user's authentication token so that they don't have to authenticate every time when app needs to access a folder in their dropbox. The tokens will all be stored on the server side.

What would be a proper implementation here, especially in terms of user security? Should I store the user tokens in flat files or databases? plain or encrypted?

Comment: I'd like to know too! The SDK example stores the tokens in an sqlite database, but I don't think this is best practice. :-(

Comment: The underlying question here, regarding best practices for secret values that need to be retrievable, is more general than the Dropbox API. For example, here's a similar question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23282/storing-oauth-and-other-authentication-tokens There are likely more resources available online from more qualified sources, so please share ay relevant links anyone!